# Meaning of phrase "the day it is due"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> You should probably start writing your essay on "To Kill a Mockingbird" sometime before the bus ride to school the day it is due.

I can't understand the last part of sentence "the day it is due"

Does it mean the reader should start writing an essay and do it in his/her free times before bus arrival?

The word *sometime* is not plural. Does it mean the reader just have to write essay in one day?

Answer (score 1):

What the text means is that the writer should start on the essay before s/he catches the bus to school on the day that the essay has to be handed in.

**The day that something is due** means the day that it has to be delivered or completed or paid.

People also talk about **the due date** meaning that date by which something must be done - often the date by which a debt must be repaid.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Due+Day

Comment: Isn't using this phrase awkward?

Comment: We don't usually say **the day that something is due**. We say that something **is due on/by (whatever day)** or that **the due date is (whatever date)**. And these are perfectly idiomatic phrases.